# Count how many times the app is open using shared preferences

Tags: flutter, count, widget, sharedpreferences

I have a widget who should be shown on home screen after a number of app open events. I know I have to use shared preferences, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int value = 0;
// when app open event call get the int to check last time value value.

value = prefs.getInt("key") ?? 0 : prefs.getInt("key");

// when app open event call set the int with appended value.

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setInt("key",(value + 1));

// when you want to check that how many time app opens you can use this.

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.getInt("key");

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved:

```
  final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var _count = pref.getInt(Constants.countAppPrefKey) ?? 0;
    _count++;
    pref.setInt(Constants.countAppPrefKey, _count);
    emit(state.copyWith(showFeedback: _count > WlConfig.countNumber));
  }
```